# ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and Observable.subscribe in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to wrap my head around best practice when using Observables alongside `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

The example demonstrates the common scenario of wanting to show some kind of loading message (or a simple spinner animation perhaps):

[Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QhqKigbUi343raXeX21D?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `Are we loading?: {{loadingMessage}}`,

  // Obviously "Default" will notice the change in `loadingMessage`...
  // changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default

  // But what is best practice when using OnPush?
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class App implements OnInit {

  private loadingMessage = "Wait for it...";

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    // Pretend we're loading data from a service.
    // This component is only interested in the call's success
    Observable.of(true)
      .delay(2000)
      .subscribe(success => {

        if(success){
          console.log('Pretend loading: success!');

          // OnPush won't detect this change
          this.loadingMessage = 'Success!';
        }

      });

  }
}
```

I more or less understand the requirement for immutability with `OnPush` and, to me at least, it currently makes sense when talking about actual model data (likely held in some kind of store).

So, I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't the assignment of the new string value `'Success!'` trigger the change detector? As far as immutability is concerned, the value has changed, right?
2. How should lightweight internal component state (ie. `loadingMessage`) be implemented when using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`? If there are multiple best practices, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Good question.  I have two quotes from Savkin about `onPush` (since the Angular.io docs don't seem to have any info on this topic yet):

> The framework will check `OnPush` components only when their inputs change or components' templates emit events.  -- [ref](http://victorsavkin.com/post/133936129316/angular-immutability-and-encapsulation)
>
> When using `OnPush`, Angular will only check the component when any of its input properties changes, when it fires an event, or when an observable fires an event. -- [ref](http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2) (in a comment reply to @vivainio)

The second quote seems more complete.  (Too bad it was buried in a comment!)

> Why doesn't the assignment of the new string value `Success!` trigger the 
>   change detector? As far as immutability is concerned, the value has changed, right?

`OnPush` immutability is in reference to input properties, not normal instance properties.  If `loadingMessage` were an input property and the value changed, change detection would execute on the component.  (See @Vlado's answer for Plunker.)

> How should lightweight internal component state (i.e., `loadingMessage`) be implemented when using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`? If there are multiple best practices, please point me in the right direction.

Here's what I know so far:

- If we change the internal state as part of handling an event, or part of an observable firing, change detection executes on the `OnPush` component (i.e., the view will update).  In your particular case, I was surprised that the view did not update.  Here are two guesses as to why not:

  - Adding `delay()` makes Angular look at it more like a `setTimeout()` rather than an observable change. `setTimeout`s do not result in change detection execution on an `OnPush` component. In your example the Change Detector has completed its work 2 seconds before the value of `loadingMessage` is changed.
  - Like @Sasxa shows in his answer, you have to have a binding in the template to the `Observable`.  I.e., maybe it is more than just "an observable fires"... maybe it has to be a **bound** observable that fires. In which case, creating `loadingMessage` (or even a more generic `state` property) as an `Observable` itself will allow you to bind your template to its value (or multiple async values), see [this example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OiBSDA8Kcsgl4vBF15xW?p=preview).
    **Update 2016-04-28:** it appears the binding must include `| async`, as shown in the plnkr, and in [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezpbwhzowWkGQQKgn3FT?p=preview).
- If we change the internal state and it is not part of event handling or an observable firing, we can inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into our component and call method `markForCheck()` to cause change detection to execute on the `OnPush` component and all ancestor components up to the root component.  If only view state is changed (i.e., state that is local to the component and maybe its descendants), `detectChanges()` can be used instead, which will not mark all ancestor components for change detection. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSENj5Oy3WSfx0O79ouF?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I'm thinking that the best solution is either `markForCheck()` (I'm borderline as to whether this is a little hacky or acceptable). Or creating a `loadingMessage` or `state` value as an `Observable` itself, that way it can represent multiple states as per this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OiBSDA8Kcsgl4vBF15xW?p=preview). I think I'll add this to your answer and accept as it appears to cover all bases.

Comment: @PhilipBulley, `markForCheck()` is not hacky.  The [ChangeDetectorRef API doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) shows an example very similar to your use case: a component with `OnPush` has a `numberOfTicks` property that is updated in a `setTimeout()` callback, and `markForCheck()` is called to ensure the view updates.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying with the example.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I can not find this quote on blog 'When using OnPush, Angular will only check the component when any of its input properties changes, when it fires an event, or when an observable fires an event. -- ref (in a comment reply to @vivainio)'?

Comment: @alt255, I don't see it anymore either.

Comment: This saved me. My entire application was set to `OnPush`, so in order to force change detection inside of subscriptions and timeouts, running `changeDetector.detectChanges()` or `changeDetector.markForCheck()` was needed to sync the view with the current context

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, `OnPush` is used when working [directly with observables](http://plnkr.co/edit/u46clW?p=preview):

```
//our root app component
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from 'angular2/core'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `Are we loading?: {{ loadingMessage |async }}`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  private loadingMessage;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingMessage = Observable.of(true)
      .delay(2000)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution based on my simplified example. In reality, the call which returns an `Observable` isn't made in `ngOnInit`, but instead within a form submit handler. Meaning the template binding would then need to be `{{ loadingMessage && loadingMessage | async }}`.

Comment: ...Also, in reality, I'm maintaining internal state using a single property `state`, the loading is just one of several states. I guess `state` could be another internal `Observable`, as per this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OiBSDA8Kcsgl4vBF15xW?p=preview). Multiple `state` values could be pushed to it over time.

Comment: @PhilipBulley Also note that Angular2 forms have built-in observables (`valueChanges` property). You might wanna look into that too...

Answer (score 2):

With this `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` you are telling your component to only listen for changes on it's input properties.

I added loading component to your example just to show you how it works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/k5tkmcLlzkwz4t5ifqFD?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your demo, Vlado. Creating a nested component just to detect a change isn't a great solution, but it does illustrate your point nicely.

Comment: Actually, I don't know why `loadingMessage` is not rendered to `test`, as we set the value to `test` in last the `setTimeout`. Could someone help me explain this?