# Change Detection in Angular with OnPush strategy

Tags: angular

Say there's two components: CompP, CompC. CompP is the parent component of CompP and it sets `ChangeDetectionStrategy` as `OnPush`. Under this setup, if some changes happen to a property of CompC, which only affects its view. At first, I expected it would update its(CompC) view automatically but it didn't happen. If I'm correct, it's because CompP is taking `OnPush` setup. It stops the change detection which occured by CompC and flew down from the root. So here's my question: if I want that change to be updated on the view at CompC, should I use `detectChanges` method of `changeDetector` manually? Apparently, it works but I wonder if there's other way to make it work other than calling `detectChanges` or `markForCheck` manually. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386822/changedetectionstrategy-onpush-and-observable-subscribe-in-angular-2

Comment: That depends on what change occured. If it's something outside the scope of Angular, it won't be updated unless you call `changeDetector` manually yes. However, if you are using `Inputs` / `Outputs` between CompP and CompC, the changes will be updated as it is within the scope of Angular.

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder Thanks man! That helped me alot!

Comment: @AlexBeugnet Yeah I understand but the problem I'm facing is that the case when the property of CompC changes without getting affected by CompP by `Input` or anything. Since all the `changedetection`s are prevented by CompP, CompC's view won't get updated unless it triggers `changeDetector` by itself. Am I correct?