# changeDetectionStrategy:OnPush in Angular how does it work with Observables?

Tags: angular, web

When data is being subscribed to the observable and service is called, how does change-detection set to onPush react to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and Observable.subscribe in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386822/changedetectionstrategy-onpush-and-observable-subscribe-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

When you use an `async` pipe the view and its parents views will be marked as `lViewFlags.dirty`. If you don't use an async pipe `OnPush` will break on your component that subscribes. You can also use `markForCheck()`

Read more about it here: https://blog.simplified.courses/angular-change-detection-onpush-or-not/